# send Dictionary with socket Programming from Server to Client

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0

How can a dictionary be sent to the client From Server ?

I want to do I send the following dictionary

```
Dictionary rates = new Dictionary(); 
        rates.Add("usd", 47.5); 
        rates.Add("eur", 60.4);
        rates.Add("ukp", 78.8);
```

**UPDATE :**

Codes do not work.Where is my problem? Whether this approach is wrong ?

Please show me the correct code

code in server :

```
 public void GetListn()
    {
        var dataToSend = new DataToSend { Rates = new Dictionary<string, decimal>() };

        dataToSend.Rates.Add("asd", decimal.Parse("12.23"));
        dataToSend.Rates.Add("asd", decimal.Parse("41.11"));
        dataToSend.Rates.Add("asd", decimal.Parse("25.23"));

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, dataToSend.Rates);

        client.Send(stream.ToArray());
    }


public class DataToSend
{
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

code in Client :

```
        private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            _server.Connect(_ipep);

            _server.Send(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("GetList"));

            _data = new byte[BufferSize];

            _recv = _server.Receive(_data);

            var stream = new MemoryStream(_server.Receive(_data));
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var dataToSend = (DataToSend)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                                MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

    public class DataToSend
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> Rates { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary rates = new Dictionary();`?

From your sample code I'll assume you meant `Dictionary rates = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();`

so anyway, since you specificly asked about a dictionary, I'll also assume you can already send raw data? In that case, create a new class:

```
[Serialisable]
public class DataToSend
{
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

then in your client fill the DataToSend object, and serialize it like

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, DataToSend);
```

And send that stream through the socket.

Comment: How do I convert DataToSend in the client to Dictionary<string, decimal> ?

Comment: Make a class library "Shared Objects" or something, and include it in both projects. put the DataToSend class in there. Then in your client you can deserialize it back to an object.